# Get audio buffer in xamarin for ios

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, core-audio, xamarin

I want to port an application i wrote in adobe air to xamarin. the reason is that i was not able to get the mp3s from the ipod library with the flex framework. Now i can get the list of the audio files but i have problems to extract the audio buffer from the assets. In AS3 it's a black box but it's always export the data as a byte array with with this properties:

- Sampling Rate 44100Hz
- 32 Bits
- floating point
- stereo

Because i don't want to rewrite all my algorithms, i want to "convert" all the songs in the same format as in AIR. so i wrote this

```
            AVAsset urlAsset = AVUrlAsset.FromUrl (url);
            NSError error = null;
            AVAssetReader reader = new AVAssetReader (urlAsset, out error);
            AVAssetTrack[] tracks = urlAsset.TracksWithMediaType (AVMediaType.Audio);

            NSMutableDictionary audioReadSettings = new NSMutableDictionary ();
            audioReadSettings.SetValueForKey (NSNumber.FromObject(AudioFormatType.LinearPCM), AVAudioSettings.AVFormatIDKey);
            audioReadSettings.SetValueForKey (NSNumber.FromBoolean(false), AVAudioSettings.AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey);
            audioReadSettings.SetValueForKey (NSNumber.FromBoolean(true), AVAudioSettings.AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey);   
            audioReadSettings.SetValueForKey (NSNumber.FromBoolean(false), AVAudioSettings.AVLinearPCMIsNonInterleaved);    
            audioReadSettings.SetValueForKey ((NSNumber)32, AVAudioSettings.AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey);
            /*
            audioReadSettings.SetValueForKey ((NSNumber)2, AVAudioSettings.AVNumberOfChannelsKey);
            audioReadSettings.SetValueForKey ((NSNumber)44100.0, AVAudioSettings.AVSampleRateKey);
            */

            AVAssetTrack track = tracks[0];
            AVAssetReaderTrackOutput outputReader = AVAssetReaderTrackOutput.FromTrack (track, audioReadSettings);

            if (!reader.CanAddOutput(outputReader)){
                return;
            }
            reader.AddOutput(outputReader);
            outputReader.Dispose();

            double sampleRate = 0;
            int channelCount = 0;
            foreach (CMFormatDescription formatDescription in track.FormatDescriptions){
                if (formatDescription.AudioFormats.Length != 0){
                    AudioFormat format = formatDescription.AudioFormats[0];
                    sampleRate = format.AudioStreamBasicDescription.SampleRate;
                    channelCount = format.AudioStreamBasicDescription.ChannelsPerFrame;
                    break;
                }
            }
            int bytesPerSample = 2 * channelCount;
            outputReader = (AVAssetReaderTrackOutput)reader.Outputs[0];

            if (!reader.StartReading()){
                return;
            }

            List flatBuffer = new List();
            List> buffers = new List>();

            string bufferString = string.Empty;

            for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
                CMSampleBuffer sampleBuffer = outputReader.CopyNextSampleBuffer();
                List buffer = extractBuffer(sampleBuffer, i, bytesPerSample, channelCount);
                flatBuffer.AddRange (buffer);
                sampleBuffer.Dispose();
            }
```

and the extractBuffer methode looks like this

```
private List extractBuffer(CMSampleBuffer sampleBuffer, int index, int bytesPerSamples, int channelCount){
        CMBlockBuffer blockBuffer = sampleBuffer.GetDataBuffer ();
        int dataLength = (int)blockBuffer.DataLength;
        NSMutableData data = NSMutableData.FromLength (dataLength);
        blockBuffer.CopyDataBytes (0, (uint)dataLength, data.MutableBytes);

        int sampleCount = sampleBuffer.NumSamples;
        float[] resultBuffer = new float[sampleCount];
        unsafe{
            float* samples = (float*)data.MutableBytes;
            for (int i = 0; i < sampleCount; i++){
                float left = (float)*samples++;
                float right = left;
                if (channelCount == 2){
                    right = (float)*samples++;
                }
                resultBuffer [i] = (float)((left + right) / 2);
            }
        }
        List result = new List(resultBuffer);

        resultBuffer = null;
        blockBuffer.Dispose ();
        blockBuffer = null;
        return result;
}
```

note that for the analysis later on I retransform the signal as a mono one.

Now i should get for the same mp3 the same data in xamarin as in adobe air, but it is not the case. I get most of the time the same values but not at the same indexes. I presume that the engineers at adobe knows what there are doing so what did I miss here?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Couple of things: (a) you dont really tell us how the data is different, there could be a bug in your program, which brings me to (b) you will be better off providing a complete project that builds and runs for someone to debug, than have folks visually inspect this and provide guesses, or have someone build a new sample from scratch which they wouldnt be able to compare to your source either.    Also, you dont need to use that ugly NSMutableDictionary API, use the Create static method that takes strongly typed objects.

Comment: @miguel.de.icaza, Hi

Sorry for the delay, i had to pause this project.
the data that i need should be identical in both framework. If i extract a buffer from the same file and also the output definition is the same, the array of data shoud be exactly the same.

Comment: @miguel.de.icaza, The as3 project cannot have a bug at this point because the process to retrieve the buffer is done in one single call defined in the Flex framework (sound.extract(...)) and the buffer is defined to be, whatever the source file is, in always the same format that i described in the previous post.
it's the reason why i assume that the MonoTouch code has something wrong, the probabilty to make an error in one line of code is not so high than in 50 lines.